# Аngular 1.5 directives отработка условий ng-show, ng-hide

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Есть примерный код

```
<div ng-show="$data && $data.length > 0">
 ....
</div>
<div ng-hide="!($data && $data.length > 0)">No files.</div>
```

Получается как. Что вовремя загрузки ,1й говорит что данных нет, 2й сразу показывает себя (что нет данных). Но потом подгружаются данные. И 2й не пропадает.

Я начал думать о таких вариантах что было бы неплохо повесить что-то тип вотчера на 2й див что бы он все время проверял (но мне еще кажется что это не лучший вариант). Или сделать так что бы 2й див отрабатывал самым последним. Но я ток начал знакомится с Англуаром и пока не понимаю как правильно это сделать.

Comment: Надо еще добавить флаг, что данные загружаются. И добваить его в условия.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko флаг?

Comment: Переменную, в которой будет хранится булевское значение, показывающее, идет загрузка или нет.

Comment: через ng-if переписать

Comment: @Konst просто заменить show and hide on if ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гм. Если в `$data` что-то есть, то чему будет равно выражение `!($data && $data.length > 0)`? Правильно, `false`. Соответственно, `ng-hide` не будет скрывать этот div. Из [документации](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide): *When the ngHide expression evaluates to a truthy value then the .ng-hide CSS class is added to the class attribute on the element causing it to become hidden. When falsy, the .ng-hide CSS class is removed from the element causing the element not to appear hidden.* Либо уберите `!`, либо замените на `ng-show`.